# visual studio codeでのphpデバック時の例外発生時の自動停止について

Tags: php, debugging, vscode

visual studio codeでcakephp3のシステムを開発しています。

下記のxdebugを利用したphpデバックを使用しています。
https://github.com/felixfbecker/vscode-php-debug

ブレークポイントを設定したデバックは普通に動くのですが、
例外時に勝手に例外発生箇所でデバックが一時停止してしまいます。

例外発生時でもデバックが停止しないようにするオプションなど何かありますでしょうか？

Answer (score 5):

自己解決しました。
visual studio codeのデバック画面の左下の方にブレークポイントという項目があり、そこで例外時のデバック一時停止の切替ができるようでした。